# Java print pdf error jhipster

Tags: java, jhipster

I tried to do a function to print all users in a pdf file in the server side but i got this error .
someone could help me ? 
this is the code :

```
public void printAllUsers(HttpServletResponse resp) throws           
ServletException, IOException, URISyntaxException, DRException {

    final List<UserDTO> page =  
userService.getAllManagedUsers();
    JRBeanCollectionDataSource dataSource = new 
JRBeanCollectionDataSource(page);
    resp.setContentType("application/pdf");
    OutputStream out = resp.getOutputStream();
    StyleBuilder boldStyle         = DynamicReports.stl.style().bold();
    StyleBuilder boldCenteredStyle = DynamicReports.stl.style(boldStyle)
        .setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
    StyleBuilder columnTitleStyle  =       
    DynamicReports.stl.style(boldCenteredStyle)
        .setBorder(DynamicReports.stl.pen1Point())
        .setBackgroundColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    DynamicReports.report()
        .setColumnTitleStyle(columnTitleStyle)
        .highlightDetailEvenRows()
        .columns(
            Columns.column("Nom", "nom", DataTypes.stringType()),
            Columns.column("Prenom", "prenom", DataTypes.stringType()),
            Columns.column("Login", "email", DataTypes.stringType()),
            Columns.column("Password", "password",  
      DataTypes.stringType()))
        .title(
            Components.text("List of Medecin")
                .setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER))
        .pageFooter(Components.pageXofY())
        .setDataSource(dataSource)
        .toPdf(out);
      }
```

The error is in this line :
            'final List page =
    userService.getAllManagedUsers();'

> Error:(196, 47) java: method getAllManagedUsers in class
>   com.mycompany.myapp.service.UserService cannot be applied to given
>   types;   required: org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable   found:
>   no arguments   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in
>   length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JHipster's userService.getAllManagedUsers takes one argument but you are calling it without the argument.  That's what the error means by `actual and formal argument lists differ in length`.  See below:

```
public Page<UserDTO> getAllManagedUsers(Pageable pageable)
```

You need to pass the `pageable` argument when calling getAllManagedUsers.  One way to do this is to create a org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest object: `public PageRequest(int page, int size)`.

Notice that that method returns a Page of users, not a List.  You need to add `.getContent()` to the end to get the List of users.  It should look like below:

```
final List<UserDTO> allUsers = userService.getAllManagedUsers(new PageRequest(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE).getContent();
```

Comment: How to get One Object ?

Comment: One object of what?

Comment: But when i want to add photos from database as byteType() it doesn't work

Comment: To get one user, just use the regular Java List method `.get(0)`.  Adding a bitType to a PDF is a separate question than this